# Difference between differnet web programming frameworks?

Tags: php, .net, ruby-on-rails, cgi

I have experience programming dynamic websites using both php and perl driven CGI code, (both on apache web server on *nix systems, though that shouldn't matter).

I do not have too much exposure to other technologies for web creation, but I frequently hear hailing and railing towards them from all forms of developers. (The most I've heard is bashing on php, but that's discussion for another day)

So can someone give me a quick run down of what the pros and cons of each web development set up is, and under what situations is each appropriate?

php, ruby on rails, cgi, .net, java, etc

Also, I frequently hear .net and java being referred to web development frameworks, whereas php and RoR are simply considered as web programming languages. Is the difference purely semantic, or am I missing the point completely?

Comment: Care to elaborate on your eloquently presented and highly educational down vote?

Comment: I did not down vote your question but for sure you are asking us for something that you could of googled a bit (php vs ruby, etc) and its quite vague and subjective.

Comment: Maybe you should do a little research. Then, come and ask a more specific question. Even here on S.O. there are probably hundreds of questions covering "PHP vs. Java vs. RoR vs. .net"

Comment: Java is a programming language, not a framework.  .NET is a framework, but not specifically a web framework (though it does have related web frameworks).  RoR is a web application framework, not a programming language.  You might want to do a search on each individual topic to understand which is a programming language and which is a framework.  That would be a good start...

Comment: It was I who presented this most eloquent and highly educational downvote. Your question can be answered [with](http://bit.ly/Idwjs) a [few](http://bit.ly/cWJkwO) [simple](http://bit.ly/3K7IES) [searches](http://bit.ly/9PBC77) and I downvoted because it is *absolutely clear* that you preformed none of these prior to posting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a great article that compares different web development frameworks: http://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/200x/2006/11/10/Comparing-Frameworks

With some googling you will definately find more.

Answer (score 1):

I would say just pick one and run with it.. but take note of what frustrates you in the environment. Then come back and research things in a few months to a year and see if there are other frameworks that improve on what you dont like.  You can ask SO very targeted questions about your annoyances at that time as well.

This includes the language itself, the tools you use to edit the code or manage database, and maybe even the community.